# Any difference between text file and ascii file?

Tags: text, binary, ascii, file-format

I hear the 2 words "text file" and "ascii file". Is there any difference between these 2 terms or they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ascii refers to [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding where text file is general file containing text in any encoding.

Comment: ok, this is unrelated to the main question, but still..so ascii coding doesn't cover non-english characters.Which encodings are prevelant for say chinese characters..?

Comment: @JanZyka:Could you tell which type of encoding is done in text file?I came to know that ASCII coding is done in ASCII text files.